# Dash API having trouble accessing COM port but values are being printed

Tags: python, debugging, arduino, plotly-dash, sensors

I'm currently working on a project trying to plot realtime data from my Arduino and sensors using the Dash API using Python, however whenever a Dash callback calls a function to open a serial port, I'm met with

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

within my dash app.

I've added some print statements in my code to debug and the data is being outputted just fine in the Python console. I thought the issue was due to attempting to access the port before it actually closed so I've tried adding serial.close() statements after using it, increasing dcc.interval, and implementing multithreading with mutex locks however nothing has worked.

Here is my code for the Dash App:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import arduino_functions as af
import database_functions as df
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import dash_daq as daq

port = "COM3"
baud_rate = 9600

low_moisture, high_moisture = df.get_moisture_data("Calathea Makoyana")
low_temp, high_temp = df.get_temp_data("Calathea Makoyana")
low_humidity, high_humidity = df.get_humidity_data("Calathea Makoyana")

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Interval(id='update_value', interval=2000, n_intervals=0),
    dcc.Store(id="arduino_data")])


@app.callback(Output('arduino_data', 'data'), Input('update_value', 'n_intervals'))
def update_store(value):
    arduino_data = af.read_data(port, baud_rate)
    print(arduino_data)

    return arduino_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And my code accessing the serial ports:

```
import serial
import time


def read_data(port, baud):
    with serial.Serial(port, baud) as arduino:
        unformatted_data = arduino.readline()

        while len(unformatted_data) != 15:
            pass
        formatted_data = unformatted_data.decode("UTF-8").rstrip().split(",")
        temp = float(formatted_data[0])
        humidity = float(formatted_data[1])
        moisture_percentage = round((float(formatted_data[2]) / 625) * 100, 2)
        arduino.close()

    return temp, humidity, moisture_percentage
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm so close to completing my project but this has taken me quite a while trying to figure out.